# MS access date format

Tags: date, ms-access, format

I have an ODBC connection to an informix database from a MS Access database and want to show the time in a query as held in the native database i.e. "dd/mm/yy hh:nn:ss.000".  It seems that no matter what format I try in Access I cannot emulate this, although I can do this in MS Excel!?

I've used, amongst others, but to no avail:

```
Format([startdatetime],"dd/mm/yy hh:nn:ss.000")
Format([startdatetime],"dd/mm/yy hh:nn:ss,SSS")
```

Any ideas?

Comment: From the Access side, what does it see as the data type of those Informix values?  `SELECT Typename(startdatetime) FROM YourLinkedTable;`

Comment: Is this a duplicate of or follow-up to your earlier question? http://stackoverflow.com/q/16692942/77335

Comment: Yes, I'm tackling a similar issue from the same data source but the timestamp is more crucial this time.
I tried the SQL statement but the database reurns an error stating that the call failed as the table does not exist!

Comment: Yes indeed, I changed that.

Comment: I've tried a second time, using the wizard as opposed to typing the SQL and it worked! It shows 'Date'.

Comment: Are the fractional seconds displayed when you cast the date to string this way? `SELECT CStr(startdatetime) FROM YourLinkedTable;`

Comment: Sadly not, just as per opening the table directly, dd/mm/yy hh:nn:ss.

Comment: I re-read Gord's answer to your earlier question.  I think the best hope is to cast the date to string from Informix before Access even sees it.  But I don't know what possibilities Informix offers you for that.

Comment: That's no problem HansUp.  I've got to leave for the day now anyhow, so I'll pick this up again in the morning.  I'll re-visit Gord's response and see if I can get this to work for me, I might have to involve one of our DBAs.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Format([startdatetime],"dd/mm/yyyy hh:nn:ss AM/PM")
```

If you need to store Access dates to the millisecond, have a look [here](http://www.devx.com/dbzone/Article/39046).